# Setting Dynamic IP Address from command line

Tags: networking

I am working with android, I have connected a ethernet cable to ethernet port of my hardware.

I am not getting any network. I am using Android O.

In linux I can use `dhclient eth0` (for getting IP addresses  dynamically)

Please help me with the command I need to use in android, as dhclient is not available in my setup.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You may need BusyBox and root access to proceed.

You can see all built-in Unix-like commands by running `toybox`.

Comment: Can you elaborate with example as how to use it? Busybox tools are known for being stripped off with many functionalities and options from there full blown counterpart.

Comment: Please restrict your answer to Android